# mvc custom routes null model on post

Tags: routes, asp.net-mvc-4

Strange behavior in an MVC4 action post. I have created a custom route as this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Projects",
            url: "{company}/{project}/{id}/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Projects", action = "Index" },
            constraints: new { id = @"\d+" }
```

When my Edit page uses

```
<form action="/COMPANY/Projects/Edit/1" method="post">
```

(where Projects is name of the controller) the update works fine, however when I use

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
```

which translates to

```
<form action="/COMPANY/PROJECT/1/Edit" method="post">
```

COMPANY and PROJECT are both dynamic values and could look like this

```
<form action="/sith-co/death-star/1/Edit" method="post">
```

the model is null. The `Request.Form` data is the same either way, it does hit the correct action. The only difference is the action string and that the model is null

**Controller**

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Edit(project project)
 {
```

**Edit**

Thanks to JOBG's answer I was able to make a discovery when I had a similar issue with another controller. For some reason the `{project}` parameter in the route was getting bound instead of the model. By changing the parameter name to `{projectName}` all was well in the land of MVC again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the name of the variable to something else like:

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Edit(project model)
 {
}
```

Comment: `ModelBinder` is really smart but sometimes assumes things like in this case, it looks like is waiting for a prefix "project" (maybe because you use the same name as the class name), another way you can fix this and still using the original variable name: `public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Prefix="")]project project)`

Comment: strange. Ok. I saw something about `prefix` in another answer but it didn't seem to apply to my particular problem. Thanks for the help